# Output Databricks json value to ADF

Tags: json, databricks, pipeline

How to set pipeline variable getting databrick return value?

Databricks/Notebook exited json:

```
"runOutput":
    [
        "{\"last_up\":\"2022-04-04 15:14:20\"}"
    ]
```

What I tried to get the date value

```
@activity('notename').output.runOutput.last_up
```

What should I try?

Answer (score 1):

From your post, the json appears to contain an array as the result of runOutput.

Can you try the following?

```
@activity('notename').output.runOutput[0].last_up
```